# 2xy-y=4+5x, what rule is being applied in the next step, that leads to (2x-1)y=4+5x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

So the question says it all, I am sure that's the next step, and I also confirmed it with Wolfram Alpha, I am trying to calculate the inverse of a function, but I have a memory loss of what rule is being applied to obtain that (2x-1)y on the right side

Comment: Factor out a $y$ from the left hand side, or going the other way use the distributive property of multiplication over addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like this, $2xy=2x\:\text{x}\:y$ and $-y= -1\:\text{x}\:y$, so if we multiply the term $2x-1$ by $y$, we get $2xy-y$. This works because $2xy$ and $y$ are both divisible by $y$. As others have said, the technical term is the distributivity of multiplication over addition, but I think you may be looking for the term 'Factorisation'.

It works because if we multiply a bracket, such as $(x+1)$ by another term, say $y$, we get that $(x+1)y=xy+y$, ie multiply each term inside the bracket by the one outside.

The process of factorisation is simply the opposite of this.

Comment: Thanks! I understand perfectly now, it's so simple yet it was escaping me.

2xy - y = 2xy - 1y, so taking out the y leaves me with (2x-1)y, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @GregorioQuintero Since my answer worked for you, please consider accepting it (the green tick under the answer score).

Answer (score 1):

The distributive property (of multiplication with respect to addition).

To go from left to right you'd call it "factoring".  To go from right to left it's called the distributive property.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see it now!